# Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services Program

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I have development a WindowsServices, but I have a problem when I try to run it.

This is the code of windows service:

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)] 
namespace ScriptServices
{

    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public EventLog eventLog1;
        public System.Timers.Timer timer1;
        private static readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
           (MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        //read the parameter from config file
        static int hours = 0;
        static int minutes = 0;
        //read the parameter 
        static int hoursFrequency = 24;
        static int minutesFrequency = 0;
        static int secondsFrequency = 0;
        static int elapsedTimeBetween2BatchFile = 0;

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("AutomaticallyRunScript"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                    "AutomaticallyRunScript", "MyNewLog");
            }
            timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1000; //Intervallo di 10 seconti
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_Elapsed);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ogni x secondi partirà un thread per andare a sincronizzare il database
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //eventLog1.WriteEntry("Thread partiti");
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                int x = i + 100;
                log.Info("entrato");
                log.Info("i vale: " + i);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                log.Error(exc);
                //EventLog.WriteEntry("Errore: "+exc.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("GestoreService start");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("GestoreService stop");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ScriptServices
    {
        static class Program
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
            /// </summary>
            static void Main()
            {
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                { 
                    new Service1() 
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }
    }
```

I try to install it through InstallUtile, it works. But if I see the TaskManager, I see the services is stopped, so I try to run it manually, then I received this error
[image]

Comment: The OnStart() method should start a thread that does the service's work.

Comment: By the way, not relevant to your problem, but the comment on your statement that sets the timer interval is wrong, 1000 milliseconds is not 10 seconds.